# Laravel ReflectionException in Controller

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I'm trying to inject the class **HotelsTransformer** without success with the next code:

**UserTransformer**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Transformers;

class UserTransformer extends Transformer
{
   ...
}
```

**HotelsTransformer**

```
<?php 
namespace App\Transformers;

class HotelsTransformer extends Transformer
{
   ...
}
```

**ApiHotelsController**

```
<?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use \App\Hotel;
use \App\Transformers\HotelsTransformer;

class ApiHotelsController extends ApiController
{
   protected $HotelsTransformer;

   public function __construct(HotelsTransformer $HotelsTransformer)
   {
       $this->HotelsTransformer = $HotelsTransformer;
       dd($this->HotelsTransformer);
   }
```

When I inject UserTransformer, it's all OK, but when I change UserTransformer with HotelsTransformer it throws me this error.

[image]

I don't know why is this happening, because I cloned UserTransformer and change its name but same error persists.

Comment: Did you check the folder name for your HotelsTransformer class with your namespace ? Otherwise It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Check your following namespace. May be it does not exist or namespace path is not correct

```
use \App\Transformers\HotelsTransformer;
```

Comment: sorry, I included the namespaces but the bold style was hiding them. Namespaces seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `composer dumpauto` command.

Answer (score 0):

Try running these commands from your terminal (from the root directory of your project)

```
// use sudo if it asks for the root permission
composer update
composer dump-autoload
php artisan config:clear
```

Rerun the app/project and try again.

These 2 commands will refresh composer loaded classes and clear the cache to make the project run freshly, hope it helps.!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved it, the filename was wrong, changed:
*app/Transformers/HotelsTranformer.php*
to:
*app/Transformers/HotelsTranformer.php*

1 hour spent on that like a crazy, good job.